# How to add css class to parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseover, rollover

I am trying to do something rather simple but I am probably missing something...

I have this code:

```
var $highlights = $j("div.ab-highlights ul li a");
$highlights.hover(
    function () {
        $j(this).children().addClass('active');

        for (i=0; i < $highlights.length; i++)
        {
            if ($highlights[i] != this)
            {
                console.log(i);
                ($highlights.parent()[i]).addClass('lowOpacity');
            }
        }
    }, 
    function () {
        $j(this).children().removeClass('active');
    }
);
```

The bottom line is that I am trying attach a class ("lowOpacity") to all elements except the one that I am rolling over. the thing is it won't work. the line that is not working is

```
($highlights.parent()[i]).addClass('lowOpacity');
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The errors messages should give some indication what is wrong. Read them :)

Comment: You should not need to set the same class on all parents.  If you specify your CSS properly, you should be able to put the class on the top level parent you want to effect and have all children automatically be effected by that top level class.  It's a matter of just using the right CSS, but it would make your JS a lot simpler.

Answer (score 4):

An element can have only one parent.

```
$j($highlights[i]).parent().addClass('lowOpacity');
```

This code would add a class to the parent of each highlight element.

You could also refactor your code like this:

```
var $highlights = $j("div.ab-highlights ul li a");
$highlights.hover(
    function () {
        $j(this).children().addClass('active');
        $j($highlights).not(this).parent().addClass("lowOpacity"); //Thanks Felix +1
    }, 
    function () {
        $j(this).children().removeClass('active');
    }
);
```

Comment: I think it should be `$($highlights[i]).parent()`, though. He has a set of elements and is fetching the parent of an element at a given index `i`.

Comment: He also has jquery mapped to $j so $J($highlights[i]).parent()

Comment: @kmb385: Ah sorry, yes, if you just replace the one line then it is correct (I was already a step further in my head ;)), but it is a rather "complex" approach. You can do it much easier... btw instead of `$j($highlights[i])` I would write `$highlights[i].eq(i)`.

Comment: @Felix Kling in your comment above did you mean? '$highlights.eq(i)'

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to add the class to all parents of the `$highlights` elements, expect the currently hovered one:

```
$highlights.not(this).parent().addClass('lowOpacity');
```

This line of code replaces the *whole* `for` loop.

**Reference:** [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

I think you also have to remove the `lowOpacity` from the elements again. You could reduce your code to this:

```
var $highlights = $j("div.ab-highlights ul li a");
$highlights.hover(function () {
    $j(this).children().toggleClass('active');
    $highlights.not(this).parent().toggleClass('lowOpacity');
});
```

---

Explanation for why your code does not work:

```
$highlights.parent()[i]
```

returns a DOM element, but `addClass` is a jQuery method. Thus you would have to pass it to jQuery again or use [`eq` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead:

```
$highlights.parent().eq(i).addClass('lowOpacity');
```

What this is doing is getting all parent elements of the elements in `$highlights` and then selecting the `i`th one.

Another way would be to first select the `i`th element in `$highlights` and then its parent.

But as you have seen above, it is much more easier and you don't have to loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

this selects immediate parent

```
$('your_selector').parent().doSomeThing()
```

select multiple elements in parent

```
$('your_selector').parents('selector').doSomeThing()
```